# Task execution exception in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After updating to the new version of Gradle and syncing my project,i started getting an error about **mergedResources** and something about the **third-party-libraries**.When i try to sync now or build or even clean my project, i get these errors :

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

and the following exception:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: [raw/third_party_licenses] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\src\main\res\raw\third_party_licenses    [raw/third_party_licenses] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\build\generated\third_party_licenses\res\raw\third_party_licenses: Error: Duplicate resources
[raw/third_party_license_metadata] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\src\main\res\raw\third_party_license_metadata [raw/third_party_license_metadata] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\build\generated\third_party_licenses\res\raw\third_party_license_metadata: Error: Duplicate resources
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:296)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
    Caused by: [raw/third_party_licenses] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\src\main\res\raw\third_party_licenses  [raw/third_party_licenses] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\build\generated\third_party_licenses\res\raw\third_party_licenses: Error: Duplicate resources
    [raw/third_party_license_metadata] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\src\main\res\raw\third_party_license_metadata [raw/third_party_license_metadata] C:\Users\Steli\Dropbox\Android_Projects\Dokkan-Cards-precommit\app\build\generated\third_party_licenses\res\raw\third_party_license_metadata: Error: Duplicate resources
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.checkItems(DataSet.java:473)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:261)
        at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:55)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:267)
        ... 48 mor

    e
```

I tried looking into the Gradle folder,the gradle-wrapper file, the external libs directory etc but couldn't figure it out!Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated resources in **raw** folder namely third_party_license_metadata and third_party_licenses.

**Sol:**
Delete either of them and rebuild project.

Comment: hi and thanks for replying, i deleted the metadata one but nothing.Should i also delete the other one or could that cause a problem?

Comment: clean the project and rebuild. If same error, delete the other one too. BTW, did you add resources in raw folder intentionally?

Comment: thanks that fixed it! Also, no I didn't add any resources to the raw folder intentionally!

Comment: If possible, try tips [force majeure]